# Can custom controls be authored in MAUI like WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, maui, .net-maui

.Net WPF has a lot of ways to make custom `UIElement`s, `FrameworkElement`s, `Control`s & etc. [Microsoft Control Authoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Can analogous custom MAUI elements/controls be created like the WPF ones below?

```
// numerous base classes
public class CustomElementBase : FrameworkElement { ... }
public class CustomUIElementBase : UIElement { ... }
public class CustomControlBase : Control { ... }

// numerous inherited classes 
public class CustomButtonElement : CustomElementBase { ... }
public class CustomButtonControl : CustomControlBase { ... }
```

There aren't many details on how this is done from [Microsoft Maui Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/)

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: A control is a c# class. You can subclass any existing control. Consider starting with `ContentView` or `StackLayout`. To simply set default properties on a `Button` or `Entry`, consider a `Style`. For deeper, platform-specific tweaks, define a `Handler`. Because Maui has to map its controls on to each platform's native controls, you won't start at a low level, such as writing a Paint/Draw method for a user control on WinForms or WPF. (Consider `Skia` `Canvas` in a `ContentView` if you want direct drawing of lines and shapes.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can subclass controls and extend or customize them:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create

You can also create entirely custom controls yourself.

In both cases, don't forget to register the handlers in the MauiAppBuilder (MauiProgram.cs).

I have developed my first MAUI control, you are welcome to have a look at how I did it: https://github.com/ewerspej/epj.RadialDial.Maui